# angular material multi select dropdown

Tags: angular, angular8

.html file

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline" >
        
        <mat-select [formControl]="groups"  [(value)] ="selectedGroups" multiple>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let Group of Groups; let i = index" [value]="Group.value" color="primary-50"  (onSelectionChange)="onSelectGroup($event)">{{Group.label}}</mat-option>
          <div style="margin: 10px; float: right;">
          </div>
          </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
```

.ts file

```
  onSelectGroup(event: {
    isUserInput: any;
    source: { value: any; selected: any };
  }) {
    if (event.isUserInput) {
      if (event.source.selected === true) {
        this.selectedGroups.push(event.source.value);
        console.log(event.source.value)
      } else {
        console.log(event.source.value)
        this.selectedGroups = this.selectedGroups.filter(d => d !== event.source.value)
      }
   
      
    }
  }
```

"GroupId": [
"a11_a1_41237_4560",
"test_g1234_41237_4560"
],

Response is get but into UI , the selected value didn't be shown

Comment: can you provide more details what is not working?also can you share the response?

Comment: In UI, Can't get the selected values. The response comes correctly on Json But doesn't display the selected values.

Comment: The check box values get from API, (ID and Name), Into the UI Name should be shown and the selected relevant label's ID will be saved into Post. Successfully saved and response got. But in The UI  the Selected Names are not displayed

Comment: https://angular-mat-select-example-4zqkpi.stackblitz.io is your problem exist in this example?

Comment: yes, When selecting and posting the values The response comes correctly, but selected values not shown in UI